# DIY Slice Extension method vs Array.Copy vs "any other options" for dicing byte arrays

Tags: .net, arrays, slice

```
Public Function Slice(data As Byte(), start As Integer, len As Integer) As Byte()
    Dim b(len - 1) As Byte
    For i = start To start + len - 1
        b(i - start) = data(i)
    Next
    Return b
End Function
```

Test case:

```
dim data as byte()={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
dim b=slice(data,3,5)
```

VS

```
dim b(5-1) byte
array.copy(b,0,data,3,5)
```

What would be the benefit of array.copy as opposed to having a simple Slice extension method?
Especially when we are **SURE** the data lengths and indexes will never fall out of range.
Also are there other handy options available in the framework for byte array handling (both for *performance* & *convenience*)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a very good library here [Lightweight extension methods for ArraySegment, particularly useful for byte arrays.](http://arraysegments.codeplex.com/)

this effort really helps.